# Can I execute multiple control files by one command?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have following 3 control files which I have to execute on my DB server-

1. X.ctl
2. Y.ctl
3. Z.ctl

I know the command to execute them one by one which is as follows -

```
sqlldr PP_DBUSER/PP_DBUSER control=X.ctl log=X.log
```

However, can anybody tell me if it is possible to execute all the 3 files with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sir, You cannot.
But you can run 3 instances of sqlldr concurrently, each with a diffrent control file.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Can you please elaborate on "run 3 instances of sqlldr concurrently" with an example. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You just open three different cmd windows and run in each of them a different sqlldr

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Daniel is correct and you cannot execute multiple .ctl files with a single sqlldr command; however, you can put multiple sqlldr commands in one batch/script file and run a single command to execute. This works well if this will need to be repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Execute in CMD:

```
for %i in (*.ctl) do sqlldr user/pass@tns control=%~ni.ctl log=%~ni.log
```

or

```
for %%i in (*.ctl) do sqlldr user/pass@tns control=%%~ni.ctl log=%%~ni.log
```